# Angular Universal: Route not being rendered

Tags: angular, angular-universal

After a few hours of struggling to make my site Universal to support Server Side Rendering, I noticed that the base route `''` of the site is not rendered by the server. The browser always waits for the whole site to load and then displays the home page. No errors are displayed on the server or the browser.

All other routes are being rendered on the server if called directly from browser, including the ones that have resolvers. Interestingly, I have the route `/Home` to redirect to `''` and calling `/Home` directly from the browser renders in the server.

Any suggestions on where to start to look for the issue?

*The repo is [here](https://github.com/cornopaez/portfolio2.0/tree/dev1.1) as I don't even know what code to post for this issue.*

Comment: What did you do to solve this? I am running into the opposite issue, where ONLY the base route loads.

Comment: @Willie I never did figure out the issue with that old version of Angular Universal. I have since recompiled my app using a newer version of Angular that includes Universal by default. The new version creates most of the base code and just works. Good luck!

Comment: I got it to work. It ended up being an Apache related issue in Windows. The same exact code and bundle worked in Linux... there is probably something wrong with the config file for the windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating  my app to Angular Universal. Everything worked fine except the root page was not rendered serverside.

After some googling and commenting out parts of my server script, I realized that I had forgotten to remove the line that served the Angular app before the migration.

This was my code:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import * as express from "express";
import * as helmet from "helmet";
import * as path from "path";
import * as favicon from "serve-favicon";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import {ngExpressEngine} from "@nguniversal/express-engine";
import {provideModuleMap} from "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

// config
app.use(helmet());
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../../favicon.ico')));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/frontend/browser"))); // <- statically serving the Angular app

const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require(path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/frontend/server/main"));

// rendering engine (angular universal)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/frontend/browser"));

// routing
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../public")));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));
app.use("/images", require("./routes/images"));

app.get('*.*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/frontend/browser"), {
    maxAge: '1d'
}));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res}, (err, html) => {
        if (html) {
            res.send(html);
        } else {
            console.error(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;
```

After removing `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/frontend/browser")));`, Universal was now rendering the root page without a problem.

Comment: In which file have too change?